# I'm having trouble in finding out Parent node in Binary Search Tree Java Program

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

This program is to find out the parent node out of the elements given in this array and if no parent node available we need to print the same element.

```
import java.util.*;
public class BSTOR {
    static class Node  
    {  
        int key;  
        Node left, right, parent;  
    } 

    // A utility function to create a new BST Node  
    static Node newNode(int item)  
    {  
        Node temp = new Node();  
        temp.key = item;  
        temp.left = null; 
        temp.right = null;  
        temp.parent = null;  
        return temp;  
    }  

    enter code here

    // A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST  
    static void inorder(Node root)  
    {  
        if (root != null)  
        {  
            inorder(root.left);  
            System.out.print("Node : "+ root.key + " , ");  
            if (root.parent == null)  
            System.out.println("Parent : NULL");  
            else
            System.out.println("Parent : " + root.parent.key);  
            inorder(root.right);  
        }  
    }  

    /* A utility function to insert a new Node with  
    given key in BST */
    static Node insert(Node node, int key)  
    {  
        /* If the tree is empty, return a new Node */
        if (node == null) return newNode(key);  

        /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
        if (key < node.key)  
        {  
            Node lchild = insert(node.left, key);  
            node.left = lchild;  

            // Set parent of root of left subtree  
            lchild.parent = node;  
        }  
        else if (key > node.key)  
        {  
            Node rchild = insert(node.right, key);  
            node.right = rchild;  

            // Set parent of root of right subtree  
            rchild.parent = node;  
        }  

        /* return the (unchanged) Node pointer */
        return node;  
    }  

     int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x) 
       { 
           if (r >= l) 
           { 
                   int mid = l + (r - l) / 2; 

                   // If the element is present at the 
                   // middle itself 
                   if (arr[mid] == x) 
                       return mid; 

                   // If element is smaller than mid, then 
                   // it can only be present in left subarray 
                   if (arr[mid] > x) 
                       return binarySearch(arr, l, mid - 1, x); 

                   // Else the element can only be present 
                   // in right subarray 
                   return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, r, x); 
           } 

           // We reach here when element is not present 
           // in array 
           return -1; 
       } 



    enter code here
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        {  


            BSTOR ob = new BSTOR(); 
            System.out.println("Insert the No. of your Employees");
            Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
            Node root = null;  



            // print iNoder traversal of the BST  
            inorder(root);
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int arr[]=new int[n];
            System.out.println("Insert the Employee Id's of your Orgn");
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
             {
                 arr[i]= sc.nextInt(); 
             }

            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
             {
                 System.out.println(arr[i]+"");
             }
            System.out.println("Insert the Employee ID  which you want to search from the Orgn : "); 
            int x = sc.nextInt(); 
            int result = ob.binarySearch(arr, 0, n - 1, x); 
            if (result == -1) 
                System.out.println("Employee not present"); 
            else
                System.out.println("Report Manager  of Employee  "   ); 
            sc.close();
        } 
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please help us help you. What happens when you run it? What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Unable to find the Parent node for the Input given